# Parse Error: "Trailing Garbage" while trying to parse JSON column in data frame

Tags: json, r, jsonlite, purrr

I have a log file that look like [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/MMPMwNZv). This is a text document that looks like:

```
Id,Date,Level,Message
35054,2016-06-17 19:29:43 +0000,INFO,"{
  ""id"": -2,
  ""ipAddress"": ""100.100.100.100"",
  ""howYouHearAboutUs"": null,
  ""isInterestedInOffer"": true,
  ""incomeRange"": 60000,
  ""isEmailConfirmed"": false
}"
35055,2016-06-17 19:36:38 +0000,INFO,"{
  ""id"": -1,
  ""firstName"": ""John"",
  ""lastName"": ""Smith"",
  ""email"": ""john.smith@gmail.com"",
  ""city"": ""Smalltown"",
  ""incomeRange"": 1,
  ""birthDate"": ""1999-12-10T05:00:00Z"",
  ""password"": ""*********"",
  ""agreeToTermsOfUse"": true,
  ""howYouHearAboutUs"": ""Radio"",
  ""isInterestedInOffer"": false
}"
35059,2016-07-19 19:52:08 +0000,INFO,"{
  ""id"": -3,
  ""visitUrl"": ""https://www.website.com/?purpose=X"",
  ""ipAddress"": ""100.200.300.400"",
  ""howYouHearAboutUs"": null,
  ""isInterestedInOffer"": true,
  ""incomeRange"": 100000,
  ""isEmailConfirmed"": true,
  ""isIdentityConfirmed"": false,
  ""agreeToTermsOfUse"": true,
  ""validationResults"": null
}"
```

I'm trying to parse the JSON in the `Message` column by:

```
library(readr)
library(jsonlite)

df <- read_csv("log_file_from_above.csv")
fromJSON(as.character(df$Message))
```

But, I'm hitting the following error:

```
Error: parse error: trailing garbage
          "isEmailConfirmed": false  } {    "id": -1,    "firstName": 
                     (right here) ------^
```

How can I get rid of the "trailing garbage"?

Comment: `lapply(paste0("[",df$Message,"]"), function(x) jsonlite::fromJSON(x))` yields something?

Comment: I copied a block of json data from an html document into a new text file and was also getting this error. Echoing the above comment, what solved this problem for me was manually adding a single open bracket ( [ ) at the top of my json data text file and a single close bracket ( ] ) at the end.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`fromJSON()` isn't "apply"ing against the character vector, it's trying to convert it all to a data frame. You can try

```
purrr::map(df$Message, jsonlite::fromJSON)
```

what @Abdou provided or

```
jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub("\\n", "", df$Message)))
```

The latter two will create data frames. The first will create a list you can add as a column.

You can use the last method with `dplyr::bind_cols` to make a new data frame with all the data:

```
dplyr::bind_cols(df[,1:3],
                 jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub("\\n", "", df$Message))))
```

Also suggested by @Abdou is an almost pure base R solution:

```
cbind(df, do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, lapply(paste0("[",df$Message,"]"), function(x) jsonlite::fromJSON(x))))
```

Full, working, workflow:

```
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

df <- read.table("http://pastebin.com/raw/MMPMwNZv",
                 quote='"', sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)

bind_cols(df[,1:3], stream_in(textConnection(gsub("\\n", "", df$Message)))) %>%
  glimpse()
## 
 Found 3 records...
 Imported 3 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
## Observations: 3
## Variables: 19
## $ Id                  <int> 35054, 35055, 35059
## $ Date                <chr> "2016-06-17 19:29:43 +0000", "2016-06-17 1...
## $ Level               <chr> "INFO", "INFO", "INFO"
## $ id                  <int> -2, -1, -3
## $ ipAddress           <chr> "100.100.100.100", NA, "100.200.300.400"
## $ howYouHearAboutUs   <chr> NA, "Radio", NA
## $ isInterestedInOffer <lgl> TRUE, FALSE, TRUE
## $ incomeRange         <int> 60000, 1, 100000
## $ isEmailConfirmed    <lgl> FALSE, NA, TRUE
## $ firstName           <chr> NA, "John", NA
## $ lastName            <chr> NA, "Smith", NA
## $ email               <chr> NA, "john.smith@gmail.com", NA
## $ city                <chr> NA, "Smalltown", NA
## $ birthDate           <chr> NA, "1999-12-10T05:00:00Z", NA
## $ password            <chr> NA, "*********", NA
## $ agreeToTermsOfUse   <lgl> NA, TRUE, TRUE
## $ visitUrl            <chr> NA, NA, "https://www.website.com/?purpose=X"
## $ isIdentityConfirmed <lgl> NA, NA, FALSE
## $ validationResults   <lgl> NA, NA, NA
```

Comment: How can I use `purrr::map(df$Message, jsonlite::fromJSON)` in a dataframe? So that I don't lose the time stamps?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, can you add `cbind(df[,1:3], do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, lapply(paste0("[",df$Message,"]"), function(x) jsonlite::fromJSON(x))))`? It uses the `plyr` package.

Comment: Still getting a parse error with `dplyr::bind_cols(df[,1:3],
                 jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(gsub("\\n", "", df$Message))))` ? Are you using the pastebin file with the weird indentation kept intact?